# Proving a sequence of functions bounded but the limiting function unbounded

Tags: analysis

I am looking to find a sequence of functions $f_n$ that converges to a function $f$ pointwise, where all functions $f_n$ are bounded, but $f$ is unbounded.

I have thought of an example on this site where the sequence of function $f_n$: (0,1) $\rightarrow$ $R$ defined by:

$f_n$$(x)$ = $\frac{n}{nx+1}$.

I believe that this converges pointwise to the limit $f(x)$= $\frac{1}{x}$ and that each $f_n$ is bounded on (0,1), but how is that $f(x)$ is unbounded? I thought $f(x)$= $\frac{1}{x}$ was bounded. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Is it because $\frac{1}{x}$ sends you to +$\infty$? And is the sequence of functions ($f_1(x), f_2(x),...$) bounded because they’re bounded by $f_n(x)$?

Comment: So, ..., what do you believe $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} 1/x$ is?

Comment: You should be able to use "optimization" from calculus  to find the minimum and maximum of $f_n$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @FredFosterDavisjr.Besides the example you gave, and for which Eric Towers gave you a hint on how to proceed, you can cook-up many other functions. Here is another one, which is also continuous in $(0,1)$. For each $n$, define $f_n$ so that $f(1/n)=n$, $f_n(1/2n)=0$, linear between $1/(2n)\leq x\leq 1/n$, and between $1/n\leq x\leq 2/n$, and $f_n(x)=0$ for $0<x<1/(2n)$ and $2/n<x<1$. See if you can plot this function. $f_n$ converges poitnwise to $0$, each $f_n$ is bounded ($\|f_n\|_\infty\leq n$), and each $f_n$ is continuous.

Comment: @eric towers I don’t understand.

Comment: Let me reframe my question. Is f unbounded because x sends everything to 1/x instead of a finite constant?

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine your $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{nx+1}$.
$$  f_n'(x) = \frac{-n^2}{(nx+1)^2}  $$
and we see that $f_n'(x) < 0$ for any real $x$ so is (strictly) monotonically decreasing on $(0,1)$.  Since "bounded" discusses the magnitude of $|f_n(x)|$, we check both endpoints to see which one gives the largest modulus.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f_n(x) = n  \text{ and}  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} f_n(x) = \frac{n}{n+1}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so $|f_n(x)| \leq n$ (on $(0,1)$).  Therefore, each $f_n$ is bounded.

(Recall the definition of "bounded": "There exists a constant, $M$, such that for all $x$ in the domain of $f_n(x)$, $|f_n(x)| \leq M$."  In particular, for $f-n$  take $M = n$.  Sometimes "bounded" is defined as $|f_n(x)| < M$, in which case, take $M = n+1$.  There's no effective difference in these two definitions since there is always an $M+1$ in the reals.)

Now, letting the limit run along the direction of the index of your collection of functions,
$$  f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{x+1/n} = 1/x  \text{.}  $$
Let us once again examine the extrema of this function.
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{-1}{x^2} < 0  \text{, }  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{x} &= \infty  \text{, and}  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \frac{1}{x} &= 1 \text{.}  
\end{align*}
We see that $f(x)$ is (strictly) monotonically decreasing, is minimized as $x \rightarrow 1^-$, and for any bound, $M \in \Bbb{R}$, there exists an $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that for $x < x_0$, $f(x) > M$.  Consequently, for any bound, $M$, there exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $|f(x)| > M$.  Therefore, $f$ is unbounded.

(It can be illustrative to pick a sequence of $x$s with $x_m \rightarrow 0^+$.  One should be careful interpreting the results.  Once we choose such a sequence, we are looking at $\lim_{(n,x) \rightarrow (\infty, 0^+)}$ along a particular path.  Generically, limit behaviour along one path can be unrelated to limit behaviour along another path with the same destination.  Let's pick $(x_m)_{m \in \Bbb{N}} = (1/m)_m$ and study  $$  f_n(x_n) = \frac{n}{n x_n + 1} = \frac{n}{n(1/n) + 1} = \frac{n}{2}  \text{.}  $$  Observe that as $n \rightarrow \infty, f_n(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$.  That is, $f_n(x_n)$ is unbounded.)